# Bigcommerce custom shipping handling

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a client who wants an eCommerce site but they have to have a custom shipping service. The way shipping will work will be as follows:

When the online customer is placing the order and is shown the shipping page, this page must query the custom shipping service passing all the order information (as JSON). The shipping service will return a JSON array containing ShipmentOption objects. Each ShipmentOption object contains the shipping method name and the total price of shipping the items on the order to the online customer's address.

Can the BigCommerce platform handle the above requirement? If yes, can you please send me the URL to the pages that explain to me how to set this up or send me the instructions please?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible to accomplish with Bigcommerce, but you may be able to use ShipperHQ to host the same logic and get similar, if not the same, quotes.